# Call function from children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have this component

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    onClick = () => {
        alert('Yay');
        this.props.setWhatever()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Bar>
                <input 
                    type='radio'
                    checked={this.props.getWhatever}
                    onClick={() => this.onClick()} />
            </Bar>
        )
    }
}


class Bar extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <label>
               {this.props.children}
            </label>
        )
    }
}
```

The `this.onClick()` is not executed. When I change `onClick={() => this.onClick()}` to `onClick={this.onClick()}` it works, but ends in an endless loop. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.
Arrow functions automatically binds `this` to the parent/outside components or the context where the function is defined/executed.

- `onClick={() => this.onClick()}` - when the click happens `this`
  actually refers to the input button and not your component.
- `onClick={this.onClick()}` - A closure is created and executed as    soon as your component is rendered.
- `onClick={this.onClick}` - A    closure is created and executed when click has happened.

Please bind all your functions in constructor and avoid arrow functions.

```
constructor(props){this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)}
...
onClick() {...}
...
<input onClick={this.onClick} />
```

Please read more about arrow functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

**Update:**
Avoid arrow functions in places where you would want to use `this` inside that arrow functions.

Comment: I agree with your answer. The problem is in losing the this reference. However, I don't think you should avoid using arrow function syntax but avoid using this inside arrow function because of its unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

By setting the `<input />` element's `onClick` prop to `onClick={this.onClick()}`, this causes the `onClick` function defined in `Foo` to be called each time the `<input />` element is rendered.

Calling Foo's `onClick` will in turn call `this.props.setWhatever()` which, as I understand from you question, causes the `<Foo/>` component to re-render. Re-rendering the Foo component triggers the cycle to repeat again, which causes the endless loop behavior that you're noticing.

By setting the `onClick` prop to `onClick={() => this.onClick()}`, you're instead (locally) declaring an arrow function, and passing that to the `onClick` prop (rather than calling it immediately as detailed above).

With this "arrow function approach", when the input element is clicked, that event triggers the function that you defined and passed to the `onClick` prop to be called as a side effect of that user event.

Hope that clarifies things :-)

#### Update

There are a few ways to pass extra arguments from an `onClick` handler. One simple approach would be:

```
{/* Inside render() */}
<input type='radio' checked={this.props.getWhatever} 
       onClick={(event) => this.onClick(event, 'some', 'other', 'arguments')} />
```

And then update your components `onClick` method:

```
onClick = (event, second, third, fourth) => {
    console.log(second, third, fourth); // 'some', 'other', 'arguments'
    this.props.setWhatever()
}
```

Comment: In other words, do `onClick={this.onClick}`

Comment: Yes. The OP seemed to be asking "why" this approach: `onClick={this.onClick()}` failed.

Comment: Yes, I just thought the right way was just a bit unclear from you answer

Comment: Thanks for the throughout answer. What If I have to pass props in `this.onClick`?  Something like `this.onClick(kittens)`?

Comment: @Stophface you're welcome :-), Just updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: @DacreDenny Thanks for the update. When I pass the props as you proposed, I end up with an arrow function again?
`render() { return (
{fooBar.map(foo => { <input checked={this.props.getWhatever === foo}
                                                onChange={() => this.onClick(foo) } /> )}` That is my case and the arrow funtion is not working here...

Comment: @Stophface I see a few syntax errors there. Try this: `render() { return ( {fooBar.map(foo => { return <input checked={this.props.getWhatever === foo} onChange={() => this.onClick(foo) } /> } )})}`

Comment: Sorry for the syntax-errors. I did not copy & paste the whole code, but reduced it to what is necessary. Thats pretty much what I have... When I remove the arrow function and only write `onChange={this.onClick(foo)}` it dows in an loop, but adding the arrow function to prevent that from happening results in `this.onClick()` not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `onChange` event when working with `checked` attribute for `radio type input`. In your case you might have encounter with warning.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

In your `Foo` component do this,

```
<input
  type="radio"
  checked={this.props.getWhatever}
  onChange={this.onClick.bind(this)} //Bind "this" here or in contructor or use arrow function as you are using 
/>
```

Working [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-thunder-wcnxu?fontsize=14)